# Can I transfer hard drive from broken laptop to same model laptop but without a hard drive, OS, or software?

Tags: linux, laptop, ssd

My old laptop broke. I can buy the exact same model cheaply but "HDD, OS, and software not included". If I simply insert my old SSD, will it work? The old SSD is not the reason the old laptop isn't working. And, if it matters, the old laptop ran on Linux.

Comment: Sure. Windows might balk at it but if you are using Linux, should not be an issue.

Comment: Can you physically reach the SSD, without destroying the laptop in the process? They seem to like using glue and little (breakable) plastic clips more and more, instead of a nice old drive bay with a simple screwed down door.

Comment: Windows 10 and newer are much better at this than previous OS, and it basically just works.  Windows 7/8 and older you will likely have to inject SATA and/or chipset drivers.  Modern versions of linux shouldn't be an issue, but if you're still running kernel 2.6 there might issues, but it working now so it should continue.  The closer to a kernel version 6.x the better off your are.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! As long as the SSD itself isn't corrupted and in need of a new installation. I myself changed my HDDs and SSDs fairly recently and It works without any issues.